# In Mongodb, how do I get the count of the total results returned, without the limit?

Tags: mongodb, indexing, database

Let's say i put a limit and skip on the MongoDB query...I want to know the **total results if there was not a limit on there.**

Of course, I could do this the shitty way...which is to query twice.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In MongoDB the default behavior of `count()` is to ignore `skip` and `limit` and count the number of results in the entire original query. So running `count` will give you exactly what you want.

Passing a Boolean `true` to `count` or calling `size` instead would give you a count WITH skip or limit.

Answer (score -2):

There is no way to get the count without executing the query twice.